# Opening new window exactly same as the parent window using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

I want to open web page in new window/tab. I want to make the new window to be exactly same as the previous one (with all the menubar, locationbar etc).

I tried

```
window.open ("http://www.google.com","mywindow");
```

In firefox it opened new tab and in IE it opened new window. This is ok.
But in chrome it opened new window without the standard buttons. I could only see the location bar; and all standard buttons were missing.

How to make it open the new window/tab which looks the same as the parent window?

Can I make it consistent to open either new window or new tab?

Comment: That's not for SPAM right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript?

Comment: @sixFingers: I don't think so, because of the *"...(with all the menubar, locationbar etc)..."*.